# post method is not working in single page django website

Tags: django, post, django-views, django-forms, django-apps

I'm learning Django from youtube. now I'm practicing on a project but the problem is the youtube tutorial used multi page django website while i'm developing a single page website where if you click a menu item, it will scroll down to the section instead of opening a new page. I had created only one app. I am really confused because as I have only 2 html page( one main and another with different layout for blog), I really don't know how to mention the pages in views.py. I have connected post method to home function but the post isn't working.

```
  views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("This is post")
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def blog(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        print("This is post")
    return render(request, 'blog-single.html')
```

urls.py from app:

````
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from portfolio import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home', views.home, name='home'),


    
    

]```
````

Comment: Can you share template files?

Comment: Haven't you replied yet?

Answer (score 0):

When use POST method you should send `body` or some `pathparam` with your request.

You have two solutions:

**First :**
add `parameter` to your request

```
def home(request,id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("This is post")
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def blog(request,id):
    if request.method=="POST":
        print("This is post")
    return render(request, 'blog-single.html')

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/<int:pk>', views.home, name='home')]
```

**Second** Change `POST` to `GET` if you want only response from server side.

Comment: but it's not working. specially when i type home/<int:pk>, i see error. I have kept the path like this:  path(' ', views.home, name='home'), because when i type home in ' ' , i see error

Comment: write your displayed error here and i will give u solution.

Comment: actually the text i am trying to output isn't printing. I haven't connected the css a, img and js files. So it says imges not found but the text of post isn't showing